# How to replace or set a new value for an attribute in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

To make things simple to understand, I have an app in which the users input a date of their choice, could be a birthday or special event. From there I store that date in core data and fetch the results in my TableViewController. Every time the view appears, I want to retrieve the date from every object and subtract today's date from the chosen date in order to get the difference. The tableView then reloads the data. My problem comes when it's time to replace the days left and store it into the database. My problem is at this specific line, I get an error saying "Type Int16 does not conform to protocol AnyObject"

```
//In my entity DaysLeft, I have the date the user chose stored as an attribute of type date as well as a theDaysLeft attribute of type Int16
        myList[index].setValue(daysLeft, forKey: "theDaysLeft")
```

This is my full code:

```
var myList: Array<AnyObject> = []

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDeleg: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let contexts: NSManagedObjectContext = appDeleg.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DaysLeft")

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "theDaysLeft", ascending: false)
    freq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]


    myList = contexts.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!


    //  Below automatically update the days left

    for var index = 0; index < myList.count; index++ {

        var data: NSManagedObject = myList[index] as NSManagedObject

        var chosenDate: NSDate = data.valueForKey("chosenDate") as NSDate
        var todayDate: NSDate = NSDate()

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: todayDate, toDate: chosenDate, options: nil)

        let secondsInADay = ((60 * 60) * 24)
        let daysLeft: Int16 = (components.hashValue / secondsInADay)

        //In my entity DaysLeft, I have the date the user chose stored as an attribute of type date as well as a theDaysLeft attribute of type Int16
        myList[index].setValue(daysLeft, forKey: "theDaysLeft")

    }

    tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Errrr.... you should REALLY be using an NSFetchedResultsController for this, for many,, many reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll do some research on that since I have no idea what it is. I'm new to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using key value coding (KVC) you have to use objects. Instead of a variable of type `Int16` you have to create an `NSNumber`, e.g.

```
myList[index].setValue(NSNumber(int16: daysLeft), forKey: "theDaysLeft")
```

which should work provided that the value retrieved from `myList` is a `NSManagedObject`.

Still, instead you should be using `NSManagedObject` subclasses. You can then access the attributes with convenient and validated dot-notation, and you can use primitives like your `Int16`.

Comment: Great solution! thanks a lot, I only had to do a small tweak to the code, for some reason xCode was complaining. The final code looks like this: myList[index].setValue(NSNumber(short: daysLeft), forKey: "theDaysLeft")